# Is there an explanation for the following pascal code?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I wrote the following pascal code. Its main purpose is to convert a number given by letters to an integer given by digits using a function that does the opposite (convert a number given by digits to letters) :

```
Program number_to_letters;
Uses crt;
// beginning of the function convert
// the following function converts a number given by the user to letters. 
// For 12 ==>  'Twelve'

Function convert(user_input:Integer) : String;
Var
    units,tens,thousands,hundreds: Integer;
    s: String;
Begin
    units := user_input Mod 10;
    tens := ( user_input Div 10) Mod 10;
    hundreds := ( user_input Div 100 ) Mod 10;
    thousands := user_input Div 1000;
    //*** handling units first ***
    case ( units ) of
        1 : s := 'One';
        2 : s := 'Two';
        3 : s := 'Three';
        4 : s := 'Four';
        5 : s := 'Five';
        6 : s := 'Six';
        7 : s := 'Seven';
        8 : s := 'Eight';
        9 : s := 'Nine';
    end;
    //*** handling tens
    Case ( tens ) Of
        2 : s := 'Twenty' + s;
        3 : s := 'Thirty' + s;
        4 : s := 'Forty' + s;
        5 : s := 'Fifty' + s;
        6 : s := 'Sixty' + s;
        8 : s := 'Eighty' + s;
    end;
    convert := s;
end;
//* end of the function **
// begin of the program
//** the program reveive a number from the user written with letters and converts it to a number using the Function above

var
    user_input : string;
    i:integer ;
begin
    write('Enter your number : ');
    readln(user_input);
    for i:=1 to 80 do
    begin
        if (convert(i) = user_input ) then write(i);
    end;
end.
```

I get the result I want for numbers between 20-80 except when I enter 20,30,40,50,60,80. 
For example, when I go from 29 to 41 and I enter Thirty I get as result "ThirtyTwentyNine" instead of "Thirty" knowing that if I enter another number for example "TwentyNine" I get 29. 
And if do writeln(convert(30)) I get "Thirty". So why it doesn't work inside the for loop?

Comment: You should set s to the empty string prior to execute a case statement where it is not guaranteed that s will be set. Otherwise, use an `else` clause in the case statement.

Comment: If you debug this, inspecting the variables during execution, you will see what is wrong. The biggest missing skill in beginner programmers is debugging. My advice, learn to debug and get ahead. It will make a massive difference to your future programming outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Pascal clears the region of function variables before the first run, not before each run. Generally, Pascal is used for good programming, and it is not a good idea to make any operation on a variable of no assigned value (the situation when the last digit is equal to 0). Because "s" is used in the case of tens, it should have a value, i.e. `s:=''` should be written somewhere before, e.g. before the case of units.

By the way, it is an interesting side effect - declared but not assigned variable keeps a value from the previous run of the function.

Comment: "declared but not assigned variable keeps a value from the previous run of the function." Not true. Sometimes it might be so. Often not.

Comment: That is why I call it a side effect, not a stable property of a given Pascal compiler.

Comment: If you are reading this comment, and there is no other answers, keep in mind that even a down voted answer may be a good explanation of obtaining "ThirtyTwentyNine" in the loop.

Comment: It's pointless arguing about the behaviour of variables. You should say nothing. But if you must spea to them you must enforce the message that their values cannot be relied upon. Your final paragraph does the opposite.

Comment: Read again @DavidHeffernan s last comment, last sentence. But there's another equally wrong statement in your answer, and that is regarding `clearing local variables`. You can not generalize like you do.

Comment: @Tom, I said about clearing the region, not variables. Filling the region of memory with 0 byte gives an empty string, that is why "Thirty" works in the first run. Regarding the last sentence by David - don't you think that my "interesting side effect" is said not to Pascal users but rather to Pascal compiler developers to assign a default value to a declared variable, e.g. '', 0, 0.0, to the most common types of variables?

Comment: @Tom, I exactly know what I wanted to say, that is why I feel sad that you interpret what I did not say. Your "clearing local variables" strongly suggests a permanent operation at the beginning of each run of the function. Both of us know it does not take place. My "clearing the region" is a preparation of a part of memory, where local variables will be allocated, done once while loading the code of the function to the memory. "Thirty" but not "Thirty#@*G6$" or "Thirty%ds#@!" in the first run may be evidence that such preparation may take place.

Comment: I think I have nothing to add to the explanation why the code generates "Thirty" instead of "Thirty#f%^d@!" in the first run, and "ThirtyTwentyNine" instead of "Thirty" in the loop, so from my side EOT. I will not keep commenting in this thread, however, it would be a pleasure for me to read another explanation. Thank you for the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

In the `case (units) of` in the function, you can add `0` as a case label with an `empty string`. 
So you can get the result when you enter 20,30,40,50,60,80, because these numbers will produce ***0*** when you ***mod*** by 10 on ***units*** variable. `(units := user_input Mod 10;)`

```
0 : s := '';
```

Like this

```
case ( units ) of
    0 : s := '';
    1 : s := 'One';
    2 : s := 'Two';
    3 : s := 'Three';
    4 : s := 'Four';
    5 : s := 'Five';
    6 : s := 'Six';
    7 : s := 'Seven';
    8 : s := 'Eight';
    9 : s := 'Nine';
end;
```

Then in the  `Case ( tens ) Of`, you can add `1` as a case label with `s+'teen'` to handle 14-19 (except 15). 
And you can also add `7` as a case label, to avoid being printed twice when user_input = 1-9 and 70-79.

```
1 : s := s+'teen';
7 : s := 'Seventy' + s;
```

Like this

```
Case ( tens ) Of
    1 : s := s+'teen';
    2 : s := 'Twenty' + s;
    3 : s := 'Thirty' + s;
    4 : s := 'Forty' + s;
    5 : s := 'Fifty' + s;
    6 : s := 'Sixty' + s;
    7 : s := 'Seventy' + s;
    8 : s := 'Eighty' + s;
end;
```

Then for the number 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, you can use a separate `case..of` statement.
Like this

```
case (user_input) of 
    10 : s:= 'Ten';
    11 : s:= 'Eleven';
    12 : s:= 'Twelve';
    13 : s:= 'Thirteen';        
    15 : s:= 'Fifteen';
end;
```

> This is the full code

```
Program number_to_letters;
Uses crt;

Function convert(user_input:Integer) : String;
Var
    units,tens,thousands,hundreds: Integer;
    s: String;
Begin
    units := user_input Mod 10;
    tens := ( user_input Div 10) Mod 10;
    hundreds := ( user_input Div 100 ) Mod 10;
    thousands := user_input Div 1000;
    //*** handling units first ***
    case ( units ) of
        0 : s := '';
        1 : s := 'One';
        2 : s := 'Two';
        3 : s := 'Three';
        4 : s := 'Four';
        5 : s := 'Five';
        6 : s := 'Six';
        7 : s := 'Seven';
        8 : s := 'Eight';
        9 : s := 'Nine';
    end;
    //*** handling tens
    Case ( tens ) Of
        1 : s := s+'teen';
        2 : s := 'Twenty' + s;
        3 : s := 'Thirty' + s;
        4 : s := 'Forty' + s;
        5 : s := 'Fifty' + s;
        6 : s := 'Sixty' + s;
        7 : s := 'Seventy' + s;
        8 : s := 'Eighty' + s;
    end;

    case (user_input) of 
        10 : s:= 'Ten';
        11 : s:= 'Eleven';
        12 : s:= 'Twelve';
        13 : s:= 'Thirteen';
        15 : s:= 'Fifteen';
    end;
    convert := s;
end; 

var
    user_input : string;
    i:integer ;
begin
    write('Enter your number : ');
    readln(user_input);
    for i:=1 to 80 do
    begin
        if (convert(i) = user_input ) then write(i);
    end;
    readln;
end.
```

You can convert 1 - 80